# Php get one value from XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap

How to get only one value from XML. My PHP variable contains processed XML like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [EntityNameList] => stdClass Object
        (
            [EntityKey] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [KeyData] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [KeyField] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Field] => unique_code
                                    [Value] => 245
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How to return only value 245 into the screen? It looks like multidimensional array?

Comment: How do  you make this odject from an xml?

Comment: i have a function behind

Comment: You are really asking "how take value from an stdClass Object"? Why you call it xml? The answer - as from the array just change brackets to $obj->EntityNameList and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$obj = your_xml_object;
$value = $obj->EntityNameList->EntityKey->KeyData->KeyField->Value;
```

Where $obj is the xml object